# Is there any other word for "thumbs up thumbs down"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, synonyms

I am working on my college project, which is a kind of product review/feedback website. In this many users can give their comments and opinion, and like or dislike the product.
I'm very confused what name I should give to my site. I was thinking about *blabbermouth*, *popinjay*, or *loudmouth*; but they do not sound interesting. Is there any one word for "Thumbs up and thumbs down"?

Comment: Yes, "rate". I bet the domain name is taken, though.

Comment: The names that you've suggested aren't quite relative to what the website wants to do. I'm thinking to see if anything fun comes to my mind, although this is more of a name choice question rather than an English one. (:

Comment: Call it [Nero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nero) *... known for many executions ...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A neutral term--but hardly amusing or unique--is *feedback*. Personally, I'm not a big fan of the word, implying as it does a machine with a built-in device for detecting an increase or decrease and then responding accordingly by performing an operation. Example: a thermostat that controls the temperature in your home.

I prefer the term *reaction*. A somewhat humorous take on *reaction* could be *reactionaries*, but that particular term denotes an almost knee-jerk negative reaction to anything new or non-traditional. It's a common term for an ultra-conservative person who clings to the "traditional" way of doing things, whereas *revolutionary* is a term for an ultra-liberal person who eschews the traditional way of doing things.

Some other suggestions (both single- and double-word suggestions--sorry!):

- critics' corner
- lances and laurels, or laurels and lances [the one being a negative evaluation and the other being a positive evaluation]
- hits or misses
- love it or leave it
- [valence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/valence) [Psychology: The degree of attraction or aversion that an individual feels toward a specific object or event.]
- ejaculations [This is sure to be popular (titillating--itself a "funny" word) with the younger crowd, but the term actually means a blurting out of, say, an opinion, with very little thought preceding it. In other words, a gut reaction, for example.]
- cogitations
- judgments

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially it has nearly the same meaning as "approve/disapprove".

Originally it had this meaning, but the *approver* was someone in high authority.

Answer (score 0):

Superpollicate/Desuperpollicate are novelist Thomas Pynchon's Latin-derived words for thumbs up / thumbs down.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This looks like a good start, but do note that Stack Exchange seeks *definitive* answers, those which provide explanations supported with adequate examples and references so that they can stand alone. I think this answer has not been well-received as you do not provide the source in Pynchon (which works? What is the context?) nor examples of their use outside his works, or how they *might* be used outside his works. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: I agree with chaster's comment, but I'd add that you haven't actually answered the question *"Is there any **one word** for "Thumbs up and thumbs down"?"* (my emphasis), so your answer should have been posted as a comment. You can easily earn the 50 reputation points needed to access the comments privilege by posting good answers (each upvote earns you 10 pts) or questions (upvotes earn 5 pts). :-)

Comment: These are possible answers, but you need to link them to a dictionary quote.  Just provide more context or links to make it clearer.